# ASP and Windows User Logon

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I want to use the Windows logon information to check if a user can use my "classic asp" site. So if the user is logon at a certain Windows Domain network he/she can enter the site and i can use this persons Windows logon information on my asp site.

I know its possible with ASP.NET but is it also possible with "classic asp", if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER").  I beleive that this will only have a value if anonymous authentication is turned off windows authentication is on.  Heres a good reference for all the server variables: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp